# Juniper VPN (Pulse client) support in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I need to connect to a corporate Juniper VPN from my professionnal Ubuntu, I currently use a Cisco VPN but in a few days it will be shut down to be replaced by Juniper.

Because my company don't allow connecting to the VPN from a browser, I can't use the [madScientist solution](http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html).

It seems that OpenConnect supports Juniper from 7.08 version. But I'm on Xenial and my OpenConnect depot version is 7.06. Is there a way to install properly the 7.08 OpenConnect version (and why not the `network-manager-openconnect`) on Xenial? (I don't wish to upgrade, for stability reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

Works for 18.04, and according to:
https://ngkengwooi.wordpress.com/2017/05/28/connect-to-pulsejuniper-vpn-with-openconnect-on-ubuntu/ on 17.04 as well, but not tested on 16.04.
Notice that link has spelling errors in a command (It's `nm-connection-editor` and not `nm-connections-editor`)

Run `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
nm-connection-editor`

Then just insert the credentials.